# Twitter Bootstrap Banner - How to render

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is probably a pretty basic question, but I have a banner with an image on the left and text on the right.  Under the banner is just a block of color.  When the page gets smaller, my expectation is that the bits in the banner would stack (maintaining the background color for both) and the block of color (class="blue-line") would fall beneath them.

Here is the mark-up:

```
   <section>
        <div class="row header">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <img src="../images/logo.png" height="100px" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 title">
                <h2>Some Title Text</h2>
            </div>
        </div>   
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 blue-line"></div>
        </div>      
    </section>
```

and the css

```
    .header {
        background-color: #F2EBCC;
        border: 10px solid #F2EBCC;
        height: 120px;
    }

.row > .title {
    text-align: right;
    top: 45%;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/3n6Kd/

Comment: What happens instead of stacking?

Comment: post a live code so i can help you

Comment: @Ahmed:  I've added a JSFiddle link.

Comment: @Pavlo - it does stack, but the second div in the header drops below the blue-line div and loses it's background color

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<section>
     <div class="row header">
           <div class="col-sm-6">
                <img src="../images/logo.png" height="100px" />
           </div>

           <div class="col-sm-6 title">
                 <h2>Some Title Text</h2>
           </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-12 blue-line"></div>
    </div>
```

and:

```
.header {
     background-color: #F2EBCC;
     height: 120px;
 }

.title {
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
 }

.blue-line {
    margin-top:10px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: blue;
 }
```

the text go under the first column not the blue-line, but it seems to appear above the blue-line so try it in your computer because some time **jsfiddle.net** don't show code correctly.

hope it will help you.

Comment: This looked the same to me - sorry.  But thanks for the help.  I decided to completely redesign